# Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for a case class

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

Following the tutorial from http://www.smartjava.org/content/first-steps-rest-spray-and-scala, there are some unexpected error messages. What is going on? Have I defined implicit JsonWriter by the `implicit val personFormat = jsonFormat3(Person)` call?

```
scala> import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol

scala> object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val personFormat = jsonFormat3(Person)
}
     |      | defined object MyJsonProtocol

scala> case class Person(name: String, fistName: String, age: Long)
defined class Person

scala> import spray.json._
import spray.json._

scala> import MyJsonProtocol._
import MyJsonProtocol._

scala> Person(name="a", fistName="b", age = 10).toJson
<console>:45: error: Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for Person
              Person(name="a", fistName="b", age = 10).toJson
                                                       ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your session it seems as if you define the protocol before you declare your `Person` class, which would mean that you already have another Person class in scope. After defining the protocol you then re-define the `Person` class, thus the format can't be found. So to sum up, make sure that you first declare your `Person` class and then define your Format.

**EDIT**: Updated answer

Comment: Tried many different imports, including these, but the error message is still there. I edited the question.

Comment: If I do fresh session and declare the `Person` class before I declare the Protocol, the session succeeds (it returns `Person(name="a", fistName="b", age = 10).toJson`). So I assume, that you actually declare your `Person` class before you declare your format?

Comment: You're right! I tried with different class and it works! Add it to the answer and I'll accept it...

Comment: It is getting worse when the classes are in multiple files and I use sbt to compile them. It seems that they are compiled in an alphabetical order, ignoring the imports...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Can you post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem (maybe a gist in order to avoid editing the question) or ask a new question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69235/discussion-between-edi-and-mirelon).

Comment: @edi I've been struggling with this same problem in trying to get a Seq to toResponseMarshallable for hours! I finally got a successful compile by implementing your suggestion of moving MyJsonProtocol to its own file. Finally! +1

Comment: Implicits are BS.