# Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat for class. Multiple Formats inside a Protocol

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

I am using `spray-json` library to deserialize `json` objects. I want to be able to parse a `DateTime` object, specified in the [nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) library, from a json string.

I want to deserialize a json string of this form:

```
{"updatedAt": "2015-05-18T23:55:49.033Z"}
```

For this I am defining my own protocol using `spray-json`'s approach. My `spray-json` protocol goes as follows:

```
import spray.json._
// I want to de-serialize an object from this library
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._    

object CustomProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

// There are other implicit objects that describe how to format other
// classes before the one below. All of them are independent from each other

 implicit object DateTimeFormat extends RootJsonFormat[DateTime] {
    def write(dateTime: DateTime) = JsString(dateTime.toString)
    def read(json: JsValue) = {
      json.asJsObject.getFields("updatedAt") match { 
        case Seq(JsString(timeStamp)) => DateTime.parse(timeStamp)
        case other => deserializationError("DateTime expected, found \n" + other)
      }
    }
}
```

My test (using [scala-test](http://www.scalatest.org/)) goes as follows:

```
//Previous imports
import CustomProtocol._

test("Can parse DateTime from Json string") {
    val DateTimeJson      = """ {"updatedAt": "2015-05-18T23:55:49.033Z"} """
    val DateTimefromJson  = DateTimeJson.parseJson.convertTo[DateTime]
    val realDateTime      = DateTime.parse("2015-05-18T23:55:49.033Z")
    assert(DateTimefromJson.equals(realDateTime))
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
{Directory}/src/test/scala/messageJsonParserTest.scala:29: Cannot find 
JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime 

[error] val DateTimefromJson = DateTimeJson.parseJson.convertTo[DateTime]
```

Can anybody spot the error in my code?

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before. After browsing my mind and the internet for a whole day I have not been able to come up with a solution.

Comment: Are you sure both are using the same DateTime? Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040828/cannot-find-jsonwriter-or-jsonformat-type-class-for-a-case-class?rq=1 Reordering your definitions may solve your issue, as it did for me.